# I keep getting a 404 from the youTube API V3 in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube, youtube-data-api

We are actively working on moving our product from AS3 to HTML5, but until we complete the process we still have many clients using the Flash version of the Youtube API V3. We have gotten our project Key and are making the request with https://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&key=[key], it returns a 404 when the AS3 goes to get it, but returns the flash API when pasted into the browser directly.

We have `Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");` in the code. 
Here is how we are loading the API, which has worked for years.

```
_loader = new Loader();
_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
var url:String = "https://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&key=*[key]*";
_loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
```

Trying to figure out what i'm missing.

Comment: Is your player the `Chromeless` version? I mean do you have your own customised playback/controls interface? If yes, is all you require being the video file so your clients see something?

Answer (score 2):

The Youtube API is no longer working with AS3 code.

I don't think any remaining SWF versions of player will last long. Consider for any video ID, Having `/embed/` used to give the HTML5 player or else using `/v/` gave you SWF player. Now both link types return an HTML5 player. They have already started changing things.

Examples:

- HTML5 : https://www.youtube.com/embed/1SnPedRxEIU
- SWF (but now changed to HTML5) : https://www.youtube.com/v/1SnPedRxEIU 
  ( `edit:` Seems this URL returned a direct link to the SWF file. Now Chrome browser asks to download, with no browser view unless contained in html file).

The only solution is to move faster to HTML5 (Youtube expects this for browser playback).

For anyone else interested, there's the final option to just extract video file path directly from the video page's source code or instead get a JSON by using  `http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=xxxx`. From either returned text (site source or JSON) you can decode the Unicode & HTML entities to reveal the file URL. The advantage of parsing page source is that you'll find even 1080p links, but JSON version is easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution, for me it worked https://github.com/myflashlab/AS3-youtube-parser-video-link